# Join two sql result

Tags: sql

my first result looks like this

```
ID       Name
----------------------------------
1        George
2        Peter
3        San
```

my other result looks like this

```
AnotherID     ID     Note
-----------------------------------
1             1      georgesnote1
2             1      georgesnote2
3             3      sansnote1
4             1      georgesnote3
```

How I want them to look:

```
ID       Name        Note
----------------------------------
1        George      georgesnote1
1        George      georgesnote2
1        George      georgesnote3
2        Peter       NULL
3        San         sansnote1
```

My SQL knowledge pretty much limits me to achieve this. I guess I need something like UNION ALL. INNER JOIN OR LEFT OUTER JOIN doesnt work. My actual query is around 21 lines so this is not a beginner question. What I need is to join two results based on same IDs. Please someone guide me.

Comment: select n.ID, n.Name, t.note 
      from names n 
      left join notes t
      on n.id = t.id

Comment: everyone. thank you for your help. really appreciate that! fixed my queries based on given answers and chose the first answer as best since he was first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN.

check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Assugming the first table is called **first** and the second is called **second**.
The column **id** on the first table will be matched to the column **id** on the second table.

```
SELECT first.id, first.name, second.note
FROM first
LEFT JOIN second
ON first.id = second.id
ORDER BY first.id
```

Comment: it should be `ON first.id = second.id`

Comment: 8 same answers but I guess I should accept yours since you are the 1st to answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  N1.ID, N1.Name, N2.Note 
FROM 
  Names N1
    LEFT JOIN Notes N2 ON N1.ID = N2.ID
ORDER BY
  N1.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `left join`:

```
select r1.id, r1.Name, r2.Note 
from result1 r1
left join result2 r2 on r2.id = r1.id
order by 1
```

but if your *results* come from other quires try to add those quires as below:

```
select r1.id, r1.Name, r2.Note 
from (select id,name from tab1) r1
left join (select id,note from tab2) r2 on r2.id = r1.id
order by 1
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) you can find more infromation about `left join`

Comment: Why -1? Maybe some comment please?

Answer (score 2):

```
select n.ID, n.Name, t.note 
  from names n 
  left join notes t
  on n.id = t.id
```

Comment: A comment would be appreciated on why left join does not work for this.

Comment: I was trying to join another table (which is in my second query now) to my first query with left outer join. For some reason, same results were displaying x4 times and just couldn't fix it. Then I started looking for a way to join two different queries so that I can get the appropriate result. In my case left outer was not working.

Comment: Maybe you should paste those two queries

Answer (score 1):

```
Select sur.ID, sur.NAME, not.NOTE 
FROM SURNAME sur
LEFT JOIN NOTES not
ON sur.ID = not.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    T1.ID,
    T1.Name,
    T2.Note
from Table1 as T1.ID
    left outer Table2 as T2 on T2.ID = T1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` is what you need here because you want to select all records from table1 whetehr it has a match or not on table2

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, b.Note
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.id,table1.name,table2.note from table1 left  join table2  on table1.id=table2.id
```